# Selecting rows with condition on two columns together

Tags: sql-server, select

i have table with columns
Number and VAT
How can i select all rows without row which is Number=123 and VAT=15 ?
I tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE <.. zilions of conditions..> AND (Number=123 AND VAT!=15)
```

But it does not work, i need every rows and with Number 123 too but not in case if VAT is 15.
Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: You probably need some post aggregation filtering `GROUP BY....HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Number=123 THEN 1 END )>0 AND SUM(CASE WHEN VAT=15 THEN 1 END )=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then u can use this one

SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE Number<>123 OR VAT<>15

Comment: And what about the other "zillion" conditions?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one,

SELECT * FROM tablex  WHERE Number<>123 AND VAT<>15

Comment: Thank you, but this will filter all Number with 123 also, i want filter (ignore) only rows with number=123 AND ALSO vat=15, how to do that ?